# BACKUP FAIL FOR SERVER (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

Tags: sql-server, backup

Show error:

[image: blurry screenshot]

I have to make a backup of my SAP database but when I do it it shows the following error. Apparently, while investigating, it is due to the fact that my database (PRD) is damaged, but I would like to know if there is any way to make the backup by omitting the error. , this with the intention of repairing the database on another server and not damaging it in case of a disaster.

More info: my server version is SQL Server 2008 R2 (v10.50.17.02).

I need a solution to create my backup omitting that error and being able to repair the database from the outside.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) a *blurry photo of your screen is by far the worst way to share an error.

Comment: The fact that you are using 2008 R2 means you're also using a *completely* unsupported version ( that's been that way for over 4 years); it's long past you got that upgrade plan from 5 years ago put in place. The version you state, however, doesn't exist: if you're really running  that version it's a prerelease version of 2008R2, as the RTM release was 10.50.1600.1.

Comment: If you meant 10.50.1702.0, that's a *significant* concern. You are **literally** missing *14 years* of updates, security patches and all. You have a many security holes in your instance, not to mention no TLS 1.2 support...

Comment: What does the errorlog say?

Answer (score -1):

I fully agree with all the comments and concerns. Also, you should look at the errorlog to get as much details if the problem as possible.

Anyhow, this option to the backup command does what the name implies:

CONTINUE_AFTER_ERROR

This would of course render a damaged backup, and restore (if successful in the first place and done with the counterpart option) would at best give you a database in the same damaged state as you have now.